# Are there integral solutions for $(2a-1)(2^{(b+c)}-3^c )=2^b-1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, power-series, collatz-conjecture

Can anyone prove this assertion?  Or at least suggest a method of attack?  It has come up in my research.

There do not exist $a,b$ and $c$ such that$$
 (2a-1)(2^{(b+c)}-3^c )=2^b-1
$$where $a>0,b>1,c>1$ and $a,b,c ∈ Z$

Comment: How did this question arise?

Comment: The conditions imposed implies that $2a - 1, 2^b - 1$ are both positive, whence $2^{b+c} - 3^c$ must necessarily be positive as well. Moreover one can choose $a$ appropriately to solve this equation if $2^{b+c} - 3^c \leq 2^b - 1$ (this is because $2a-1$ can be any odd integer). This inequality is equivalent to $2^b \leq (3^c - 1)/(2^c - 1)$.  But this is incompatible with $2^{b+c} - 3^c > 0$, since the latter implies that $2^{b+c} - 2^b > 3^c - 2^b > 3^c - 1$. Hence there are no solutions.

Comment: For such a random-looking number theory question, it's often a good idea to include in the text any motivations you might have.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: Thanks Todd.  I'm new here.  Great advice.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg: I was comparing 2 types of sums: $S1 = x + (3/2) x + (3/2)^2x + ... + (3/2)^nx,$
$S2 = y + 2 y + 2^2y + ... + 2^my$ to see if they could ever equal one another, given specific constraints on the relationship between x and y (specifically that $y = 2x-1$) and $x = 2^n(2a-1)$

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao : Thanks. That looks fascinating. Give me a little time to digest.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao : One more thing: I can follow your argument up to $3^c-2^b > 3^c - 1$.  Can you please clarify how you arrived at this inequality?  Thanks!

Comment: That is because Stanley made an error. I do not think his argument is a disproof, but you should correct it and investigate the inequalities involved because they will give tight bounds on b which may lead to a correct proof. (Stanley's error is like 2^b < 1 error.). Gerhard "Good Ideas Come From Everywhere" Paseman, 2018.08.23.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Thank you.  Yes, it caught my attention since it means $2^b - 1 < 0$, which of course contradicts the imposed conditions.

Comment: This seems to have been occured in the (re-discovery of the)  question of the so-called "1-cycles" . In the analysis of "1-cycle" of Ray Steiner (1977) and later of John Simons and Benne de Weger (since 2003 ?) there occur a related equation and it was proved using a result of G. Rhin (1987 due to Simons) that there is no nontrivial solution. The same question was asked in MSE and I gave a comment with that same explanation as this in a comment and also a link to an (attempted) readable reproduction of the proof - but unfortunately (and unneccesarily IMHO)  the author has deleted his question.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao - your formula should contain an additional odd positive integer say $k$ making the criteria-formula look like $2^b \le (k3^c -1)/(k2^c-1)$ (This is the form which I know from the discussion of the 1-cycle). We find then easily that $k$ cannot be $1$ (known by the medieval N. Oresme), that also $k$ cannot be $2$ (the numerator in the rhs were odd then),... and so on.

Comment: For what it is worth, *Mathematica* cannot find a solution instance (though that of course does not prove no solution exists).

Comment: I'm upvoting this question because it is now apparent from the comments that it is indeed well motivated (i.e. not just a random crank's number theory "research", so to speak. Sometimes it's difficult to tell, for non-experts like me).

Comment: Mathematics copy of the question: [Are there integral solutions for $(2a-1)(2^{(b+c)}-3^c )=2^b-1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2892441) See also: [Cross posts to Math SE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2637#2638) and other posts on meta about [meta-tag:cross-posting].

Answer (score 3):

*this is a copy of my answer in MSE*
Let me rewrite the letters for your variables due to my long-time practice.
I usually write $N$ for $c$ , $S$ for $c+b$ such that $S = \lceil N \cdot \log_2(3) \rceil$ and $B$ for $b$.
Also, to simplify I write $k$ for $2a-1$, not forgetting $k$ must be odd.

I refer also to a formula of G. Rhin, cited in J. Simons [Si,07], for a lower bound of $S \log 2 - N \log 3$ depending on $N$.

So we start with your formula, simply rewritten in notation, and then adapting for application of Rhin's inequality:
$$ \begin{array} {rl} k(2^S-3^N)&=2^B - 1 \\
 k( (2^S/3^N)-1)&=(2^B - 1)/3^N \\
 2^S/3^N &= 1 + (2^B - 1)/k/3^N 
\end{array} \tag 1$$
Logarithmizing and using the Mercatorseries on the rhs gives us
$$\small {S \ln2 - N \ln3  =  (2^B - 1)/k/3^N -1/2((2^B - 1)/k/3^N)^2+ 1/3((2^B - 1)/k/3^N)^3 \pm \ldots }$$

Cancelling of trailing small terms on the rhs gives now an ***in***-equality
$$ S \ln2 - N \ln3  \lt  (2^B - 1)/k/3^N \tag 2 $$

By G. Rhin we have due to J. Simons (formula slightly rewritten to be better memorizable):
$$\frac1{457}\frac1{N^{13.3}} \lt S \ln2 - N \ln3 \tag 3
$$
So we can conclude
$$\begin{array} {rl}  \frac1{457}\frac1{N^{13.3}} &\lt S \ln2 - N \ln3  &\lt  (2^B - 1)/k/3^N \\
\frac1{457}\frac1{N^{13.3}} &\lt  (2^B - 1)/k/3^N 
\end{array} \tag 4  $$
Now taking logarithms again gives
$$\small \begin{array} {rl}  -6.13 - 13.3 \ln N &\lt \ln (2^B - 1) - \ln k - N \ln 3 \\ 
 N \ln 3 - 13.3 \ln N &\lt 6.13 + B \ln 2 -(1/2^B + 1/2/4^B + ..) - \ln k  \\
 N \ln 3 - B \ln 2 - 13.3 \ln N &\lt 6.13  -(1/2^B + 1/2/4^B + ..) - \ln k  \\
\end{array} \tag 5$$
Here obviously the lhs is increasing with increasing $N$ while the rhs stays roughly constant *(or even decreases if you increase $k$)* so we can solve for the **equality**-condition given $N$ and $\small{B=\lceil N \cdot (\log_2 (3) -1)\rceil }$ and some assumed $k$. Say $k=3$ then at $\small {N=95.05}$ the lhs grows over the rhs.

So for $N \gt 95$ there is no solution.
The cases $N \le 95$ can be done one by one finding that no other solution exists for $N>2$

Now check for other odd $k>3$.

So you are done.

---

*Remark: I think this is easier than the Simon's exposition because I do not need to refer to the theory of continued fractions here.*

---

[Si,07]  John L Simons: On the (non)-existence of m-cycles for generalized Syracuse sequences
$ \qquad \qquad $(2007) (online update of earlier article)
[Rh,87]  G. Rhin: Aproximants de Padé et mesures d’irrationalité.
$ \qquad \qquad $Progress in Mathematics 71, (1987), pp. 155-164
$ \qquad \qquad $(Reference supplied by [Si,07])

Answer (score 1):

Pursuing suggestions from the comments above, the conditions on a,b, and c imply the two inequalities $2^b \gt (3/2)^c$ and (after Stanley's analysis) $2^b \leq (3^c-1)/(2^c-1)$. For large integral $c$ this makes an integral $b$ unlikely, even relaxing the condition to $a$ a real number at least 1. For $c=1$ we get $b=1$.  You can easily compute for other small c that there are no possibilities for b.  Likely you can also show there is no solution for large a, where large means $a$ bigger than (say) 10.

**Added**  On further consideration, 2^b is like (3/2)^c, which means the right hand side will be like (3/2)^c, which may give bounds on a but does not guarantee that a is small. However, integer divisors of 2^b - 1 are special, so there is still hope for a resolution.

Gerhard "Ten Is Large To One" Paseman, 2018.08.23.

Comment: Indeed looking for an integral c with an integral d between (3/2)^c and (3^c - 1)/(2^c -  1) is already challenging and relates to open problems.  You might be able to prove some fantastic lower bounds on the size of c.  Gerhard "We're Talking Really Tight Bounds" Paseman, 2018.08.23.

Comment: That is fascinating, Gerhard.  I will digest this and see if it will help me to move forward.  Much thanks.

Comment: I hope we're not trying to prove $2^k\{\,(3/2)^k\,\}+[(3/2)^k]\le2^k$, a notorious open problem coming out of Waring's problem.

Comment: The difference between a power of 3 and the next largest power of two grows pretty rapidly, though irregularly.  If you can show that asymptotically it grows faster than (3/2)^c, then I think you can get a proof of your result.  Gerhard "Perhaps Pillai's Work Will Help" Paseman, 2018.08.23.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I thought it was rather obvious what notorious open problem the OP is attempting to prove (even before he or she added the relevant tag)

Comment: @Gerhard, now we're getting close to Hall's conjecture on differences between cubes and squares, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_conjecture

Comment: Maybe we should revisit all these and find if they are equivalent.  Gerhard "That's Worth A Paper, Right?" Paseman, 2018.08.23.

Comment: The highest perfect power  $2^b$ in the primefactorization of $3^c-1$ in the numerator of your second formula is $v_2(c)$ plus a constant say $1$ or $2$, don't have it at hand. So $b$ is at most logarithmical with $c$. On the other hand, $log_2((3^c-1 )/(2^c-1))$ is about $ 0.58 \cdot c $ - and by the previous $b$ is always much smaller than that $0.58 \cdot c$ and thus the equation has no solutions in integers (except for possibly trivially small $c$)

Comment: @yemonChoi - the question of "1-cycles" in the Collatz-problem is no more "open problem" but has been resolved initially by R. Steiner (1977) and later in generalizations by J. Simons (2003 and later). I think the problem here is a simple re-discovery (and is meaningful to ask because it can be solved). But well, a better place were MSE, of course, where it is now unfortunately self-deleted by the OP....

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I have restored the post from MSE.  I just didn't think it would matter to anyone, but I have seen your comments and understand your point.  My apologies.

Comment: @MathAllTheTime - don't mind; when I was new to MSE and MO similar things could have happen to me too. If there are further details to ask about that problem don't shy away (likely it is better to stick to MSE instead of MO with this). If you arrive at the *unsolvable/unsolved* then step out (but always keep your curiosity!)